# How to slow down Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, stripe-payments

I have any problem with Capybara and Stripe.
I write some test to check entering card numbers. Sometimes I have a broken test.

When I use chromedriver and look at him - I see, that capybara entered the card numbers very fast.  And sometimes it creates errors.

For example - I often use number 4242 4242 4242 4242 - test card from Visa. Sometimes Capybara entered 4242 as 2442, 2244 or 4224. Of course, the test had broken.

Can you help me? I don't know how to resolve this problem. Maybe, I missed something in the documentation?

Update.
Yes of course.

```
stripe_iframe = all("iframe[name=__privateStripeFrame4]").last
Capybara.within_frame stripe_iframe do
  fill_in "cardnumber", with: "4242424242424242"
  fill_in "exp-date", with: "1222"
  fill_in "cvc", with: "123"
  fill_in "postal", with: postal if postal
end
click_button "Start your free trial"
```

Comment: Can you show some code on how the numbers are entered?

Comment: You may have better luck with `send_keys` similar to the snippets of code [here](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment/issues/149#issuecomment-75344077) and [here](https://gist.github.com/iloveitaly/19ff89614b8e92a71de660c89b8a0fbf).

Comment: This can be caused by a react app that doesn’t have any debounce on key inputs when the Xhr requests key presses generate end up getting processed out of order. Are you using a custom payment form or stripes built-in form? Are you hitting stripes servers when running your tests or are you using mocks or a fake?

Comment: That problem occurs with a Stripe Button and Stripe Elements. In the second case more often than in first.  
Yes, I check all process and use Stripe without mock or fake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved same issue by sending card number digits one by one.

```rb
card_number = '4242424242424242'
card_number.chars.each do |digit|
  find_field('cardnumber').send_keys(digit)
end
```